# When I use Ecto cast to update an array and make it empty (full of nil elements) it replaces the array with []

Tags: elixir, ecto

When I pass in `params = %{ field_name: [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]}` to `Ecto.Changeset.cast(schema, params, [:field_name])` it is ignored and not updated to that value. Note that a list of nils is also the default in the schema.

`field :field_name, {:array, :string}, default: List.duplicate(nil, 10)`

`field_name: [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil],`
when passed through cast it is completely ignored and the update doesn't take place. It cannot be seen in `changes` either.

in the migration

`add :field_name, {:array, :string}, default: List.duplicate("", 6)`

Comment: The code of schema and cast itself might help.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin I just did!

Comment: Should not it be `List.duplicate("", 6)` everywhere? `il` is not kinda string.

Comment: When I use strings it still turns the array into {} in the database

Comment: I think it might be due to the fact that `[]` is not considered an empty value by default. Maybe can you try to pass `empty_values: [[]]` to `cast`? https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#cast/4-options

Comment: I tried that to no avail

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin 
https://github.com/hassanshaikley/broken is a reproduction with a failing test

Comment: @sabiwaraI I added a reproduction repo